# A* algorithm implementation

Tags: java, android

I am building an application that will calculate the route between two rooms in a building. The app supposed to display a floor plan and then show the route on it. The user enters the room they are currently o and the room they want to get to. By following a tutorial I have implemented the A* algorithm. Here the code:

Vector1.java:

```
package testalgo.ut;

public class Vector1 {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Vector1(){

        set(0,0);
    }

    public Vector1(Vector1 vector){

        set(vector.x, vector.y);

    }
public Vector1(int x,int y ){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    }
    public void set (int x, int y){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

    }


    public int getX(){

        return x;

    }

public int getY(){

        return y;

    }

public Vector1 setX(int x){

    this.x = x;
    return this;

}

public Vector1 setY(int y){

    this.y = y;
    return this;

}

public Vector1 add(Vector1 vector){


    this.x += vector.x;
    this.y += vector.y;

    return this;
}

public Vector1 subtr(Vector1 vector){


    this.x -= vector.x;
    this.y -= vector.y;

    return this;
}

public boolean equals(Object object){

    if(!(object instanceof Vector1))return false;
    Vector1 vec = (Vector1)object;
    if(vec.getX() == this.getX() && vec.getY() == this.getY())return true;
    return false;

}   

}
```

Node.java :

```
package testalgo;

import testalgo.ut.Vector1;

public class Node {

    public Vector1 t;
    public Node parent;
    public double f;
    public double g;
    public double h;


    public Node(Vector1 t,Node parent, double g,double h){

        this.t = t;
        this.parent= parent;
        this.g = g;
        this.h = h;
        this.f= this.g + this.h;

    }

}
```

CMain.java

```
package testalgo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction;
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;
import java.util.function.ToLongFunction;

import testalgo.ut.Vector1;

public class CMain {
    private Comparator<Node> sortNodes = new Comparator<Node>(){

        public int compare(Node n0, Node n1) {
            if(n1.f < n0.f)
            return +1;
            if(n1.f < n0.f)
            return -1;  

            return 0;
        }

    };
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public List<Node> findPath(Vector1 start, Vector1 goal){

        List<Node> open = new ArrayList<Node>();
        List<Node> closed = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Node current = new Node( start, null, 0, getDistance(start, goal));
        open.add(current);
        while (open.size() > 0){
            Collections.sort(open, sortNodes);
            current = open.get(0);
            if(current.t.equals(goal)){
                List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
                while(current.parent != null){
                    path.add(current);
                current = current.parent;
                }
                open.clear();
                closed.clear();
                return path;
            }
            open.remove(current);
            closed.add(current);
            for (int i = 0; i <9 ; i++){
                if(i ==4)continue;
                int x = current.t.getX();
                int y = current.t.getY();
                int xi = (i%3)-1;
                int yi = (i/3) -1;
                Vector1 a = new Vector1(x + xi, y + yi);
                double g = current.g + getDistance(current.t, a);
                double h = getDistance(a, goal);
                Node node = new Node(a, current,g, h);
                if(vecInList(closed, a) && g >= node.g)continue;
                if(!vecInList(open, a) || g < node.g)open.add(node);
            }
        }
        closed.clear();
         return null;

    }

    private boolean vecInList(List<Node> list, Vector1 vector  ){

        for(Node n : list){

            if(n.t.equals(vector))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private double getDistance(Vector1 t, Vector1 goal){

        double dx = t.getX() - goal.getX();
        double dy = t.getY() - goal.getY();

        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }




}
```

I am using PlotDigitizer to get the coordinates of every room on the floor plan. The floor plan is a bitmap. It is the first time I am doing something like this and I am not sure how to make the coordinate and the algorithm work together so the route is calculated and displayed. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For A* to be usable you need to operate off of a graph.  So you have a series of rooms, but that alone doesn't mean you have an easy graph to operate with.  Having a bitmap of a floor plan means you don't have a graph to operate A* off of.  You'll need a data structure that maps a room's coordinates onto that floor plan graphic.  Then you'll need to map paths between those rooms.  That will form the graph basis.  See the floor plan below:

[image: Floorplan]

The blue squares might be your floor plan graphic.  The green dots are points on your Node/Vector graph for A* to work.  The pink lines are the paths between the rooms.  This graphic representation isn't shown to the user.  It's just for you to visualize how the computer would understands the space.  But you'd need to have it represented in a graph data structure that maps to the floor plan.

So the user is in one of the rooms at some point (not a green dot necessarily).  The user clicks another point in another room to tell us the destination point.  Upon click the algorithm would find the closest green dot to the user's current position.  That is the starting point for A* algorithm.  The end point for A* would be the closest green dot to the destination.  Then A* would use the pink/green graph data structure to find the path between start and end points (ie green dots).  Then travel to the destination point the user clicked from that green dot.

To draw the path you'd have a series of green dots that the user would travel to move between start and end points adding it's own straight lines from user's current position to start point, and end point to destination point.

So you'll need to build the pink/green dots from Vector and Node classes by hand, and then it's really easy application of A* on top of that data structure.  If you had the person creating the floor plan then you need a more complex representation of a floor plan and you could derive the paths between rooms, but just have a graphic floor plan is complex to build it automatically.

For example, here is what the algorithm might have figured out:

[image: example path found between two points]

Given the orange starting point and the orange destination point.  The user sits currently at orange starting point.  And the user clicks the destination point.  From starting point the algorithm would figure out the starting green point by which one is closest, then travel along the pink path to the end point using A*, then walks from the end point to the destination point the user clicked.

So Waypoint models each green dot.  The neighbors array holds the dots that directly connect through a pink edge to this Waypoint.  I find it easiest to read the graph and its edges in from a file and build this data structure from that.

In this model I'm showing how also to implement the g(),h(), and f() functions using the distance formula.

```
public Vector {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public double distanceFrom( Vector here ) {
        return Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x - here.x, 2) + Math.pow( y - here.y,2) );
    }
}

public class Waypoint {
    Vector position;
    List<Waypoint> neighbors;

    public Waypoint( Vector pos, List<Waypoint> neighbors ) {
        this.position = pos;
        this.neighbors = neighbors;
    }

    public List<Waypoint> getNeighbors() {
        return neighbors;
    }

    public double h( Vector goal ) {
        return goal.distanceFrom( position );
    }

    public double g( Vector current ) {
        return position.distanceFrom( current );
    }

    public double f( Version current, Vector goal ) {
        return g(current) + h(goal);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you so much for such  detailed and helpful answer .

Comment: Could you give some advise on how to create graph in java please? Thank you

Comment: Here is how you might implement a graph using the Waypoint class I included.